# The type ConcurrentlinkedQueue is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>

Tags: java, collections, queue

Could you explain why I get the 2 errors mentioned at the title, when I try to instantiate ConcurrentlinkedQueue object, In Java SE documentation, ConcurrentlinkedQueue implements Queue and could be generified, due to that I guess I can write :

```
 Queue<Integer>  myConcurrentLinkedQueue  = new ConcurrentlinkedQueue<Integer>();
```

looking forward to hear from you, thank you .

Update : I jave already import java.util.*;

Last update : It was my mistake, for I've created a class with the name 'ConcurrentLinkedList', feel embarrassed, sorry for the time put into my trivial question, thank you all .

Comment: That line compiles fine. What imports do you have?

Answer (score 3):

you probably are using Queue from a different package maybe `javax.jms.Queue;` which would give you your current error .

```
     java.util.Queue<Integer>  myConcurrentLinkedQueue  = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
```

should work

Comment: Unfortunately, problem still exist, sir.

Comment: @RealSilhouette hmm, then you are trying to run this code in < java1.5 version, what's ur java version ?? generic's were introduced in java in version 1.5.

Comment: I believe, JDK 1.6 installed on my PC, It really maddens me .

Comment: hmm, just confirm once by checking your java version here http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're either using another implementation of one or both of these classes (something other than `java.util.Queue`, for instance) or you're building at a very old version of the JDK, one where collections weren't generic.

Comment: No sir, JDK 6 installed, I've been writing generic code for ages .

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are really using `java.util.concurrent` and not, for example, [backport-util-concurrent](http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/) (`edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent`).  The latter is Java 1.4 compatible and does not use generics.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a class with the name ConcurrentLinkedList, sorry for inconvenience .